# Image Search Ranking

Tags: images, ranking, image-search

**What are image-specific factors that contribute to ranking in [Google Image Search](http://images.google.com/)?**

Looking for what contributes to **ranking and relevancy of images above and beyond the SEO of the hosting site itself**.

My [online gallery](http://www.neoluminance.com) for example ranks well for keyword in normal (text) search but much less in image search. Furthermore, results in image search are often wrong while text search results are not. Specifically, pictures of some places or monuments often show up for searches for another place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible factors:

- ALT attribute values
- If the image is included in a hyperlink, anchor text
- Surrounding text
- Relevance of the page for keywords
- Links pointing directly to the image
- Links pointing to the page the image is on
- Keywords in the file name
- Meta data in the image

Comment: Damn! You just had to add those last two ;) They are the hardest to change generically.